# Listen on multiple IPv6 addresses

Tags: debian, ipv6

Using Debian 8.7
I have VPS server with allocated ipv6 range:
2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2/64

ifconfig looks like this

```
 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:a2:01:9a:8c  
 inet addr:172.31.1.100  Bcast:172.31.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0  
 inet6 addr: 2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2/64 Scope:Global  
 inet6 addr: fe80::5054:a2ff:fe01:9a8c/64 Scope:Link
```

I can ping the server using primary IPv6 `2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2/64`

```
ping6 2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2  
PING 2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2(2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2) 56 data bytes  
64 bytes from 2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=59 time=1.20 ms  
64 bytes from 2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=59 time=0.466 ms
```

However, when I try to use other IPs assigned I get no response.
e.g.
`ping6 2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::3`
`ping6 2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::4`
`ping6 2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::5`
`ping6 2a01:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::6`

This is not limited to ping but also to any other request.

I would like to serve apache from multiple IPv6 addresses (not whole range).
Where/ how should I change configuration to listen on more than 1 IPv6 address?
Both HTTP and ping should work (Ping is used for uptime checks for specific services).

Comment: You haven't assigned a range. You've assigned 2a01:xxx::2 in a /64 subnet, in the same way that you have also assigned 172.31.1.100 in a /24 (255.255.255.0) subnet for ipv4